# How to get users data from database to a table using vue js in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a  problem retrieving data from mysql to a table using Axios and Vue Js. I get an error http://localhost:8000/api/allusers 403 (Forbidden).

This is my code:
UserController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\user;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('role:user|superadministrator');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('user.index');
    }
    public function getusers(){
    return User::latest()->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

My api route

```
Route::get('/allusers','UserController@getusers');
```

My table

```
 <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                     <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                      <td><a href="#" @click="editModal(user)"><i class="fa fa-edit text-blue"></i></a>
                      /
                       <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(user)"><i class="fa fa-trash text-red"></i></a>

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

The scripts

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
         return{
         editmode:true,
         users:{},
           form: new Form({
           id:'',
           name:'',
           email:'',       
           })

         }
    },

    methods:{
     loadUsers(){
     axios.get("/api/allusers").then(function(response){
    this.users=response.data.data;
    console.log(response)
          }.bind(this))
       
            },

        created() {
            this.loadUsers();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way I can access the auth table using Axios. Also am using Laratrust to assigned the user roles.

Comment: Do you have a logged in user? And does the logged in user have a role of user or superadministrator?

Comment: @Donkarnash yes I have a logged in user superadministrator

Comment: Are you on Laravel 8? Check what you have in `config/auth.php` under guards > api

Comment: @Donkarnash Laravel 7

Comment: Try running `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @Donkarnash 
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225819/discussion-between-user3736334-and-donkarnash).